# vba and outputing data from hidden/Non-enabled multipages

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with various tabs on a multipage. I am using datepickers (Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0) and textboxes on the different tabs.

The problem occurs when I want to get the data from the hidden, non-enabled or simply non-active multipages to output to the worksheet.

For example, Multipage1 has a Date of Birth, Multipage 2 has a start date.

When I press the command button to execute the output of ALL data across all multipages to the worksheet, it will only output the value for the currently active multipage. The other values are default.

Mulitpage1 active means it will return D.O.B but returns a blank/default start date from Multipage2

Multipage2 active means it will return  start date but returns a blank/default D.O.B from Multipage1

Multipage 3 active means neither D.O.B or Start Date will output anything other than their default values.

(Presume all fields across all multipages have actually been completed with a value)

Is there a way around this?

The command button to output data has a long list of statements like these:

```
Cells(6, 2) = Address1TextBox.Value
Cells(7, 2) = Address2TextBox.Value
Cells(8, 2) = Address3TextBox.Value
```

Comment: Post the code in the command button at least. Also what are the controls on each multi-page that you are trying to get values from - comboboxes, textboxes, etc ?

Comment: Date picker for the date, textboxes for everything else. Added a few lines of the command button.

Comment: You will have to be more specific about which datepicker you are using...

Comment: Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP6)

Comment: Just for some more clarity, the text boxes on hidden or non-enabled multipages output fine. Date picker seems to be the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatePicker was the issue here and I know textboxes do not have an issue with being output to the worksheet while hidden/disabled. 
With this in mind I had to resort to using a textbox with validation which only allows the user to enter a date.

Answer = Don't use Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0